# idb file randomly being deleted/going missing - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: mariadb, innodb, ibdata

Full disclosure, I'm a website owner, not a professional DBA. I hope this question is OK.

I'm trying to discover why an idb file is, seemingly randomly at a rate of around once every 4-7 days, disappearing from our web server (the associated frm file remains intact). This file is related to a well-supported Wordpress plugin but we seem to be the only user affected by this issue. Unfortunately I see nothing in the mysql error logs and neither the plugin developer nor our web host can explain what's going on. Is there any auditing/logging I can enable to give me some clue as to why this may be happening? We're running MySQL Version 10.6.14-MariaDB. Many thanks.

Comment: Does it come back? Could it bd a virus scanner?

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't come back, I need to replace it manually from backup. The virus scanner is an interesting suggestion, I'll look into that.

Comment: Rohit, I think you've solved it, I've found something in the logs (now just need to investigate if it's a false positive or not). Thanks so much!

Comment: What us the full path and name of the file?  Which Plugin?  (It would be hard to "accidentally" remove just the .ibd file.)  MariaDB has some sort of audit plugin ($$).

Comment: [mariadb's audit plugin is free](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-audit-plugin/). It more at higher level and I don't think will notice a single file going missing. Copying the file back is an exceptionally fragile restore mechanism that will fail once the table changes. Take a copy with [flush tables for export](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces/#copying-transportable-tablespaces). Also perhaps make a hardlink to the file that way it will still be there if it gets deleted, then you can hardlink it back. Maybe monitoring with linux `auditd` will identify the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for those additional comments, much appreciated. The problem was indeed an antivirus scanner rule being triggered by a string in this table, although I'm not entirely sure why it seems to have been being triggered somewhat randomly. I've removed the string in question (it was a false positive) and everything seems fine now. Thanks again to you all for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Glad you found it @Jamie. A more reliable setup would be to add the datadir as an excluded directory in the AV configuration. Would you like to write up a quick answer so the next person that encounters this issue will have an existing answer?

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing our Linux Malware Detect (maldet) logs revealed that a Yara rule was being triggered by the forum signature of a user account whose details were contained in the database table related to the missing idb file, and consequently this file was being moved by maldet to a quarantine directory. On closer examination it was clear that the user account had been created by a spammer and could be safely deleted. As suggested, a solution to avoid this problem in future could be to exclude the idb files directory from further AV/malware scans.